# Wheel of fortune statistical simulation java

Tags: java, random, statistics

The task is to simulate a wheel of fortune, which you are allowed to turn ten times.
You can spin as many times as you like, but as soon as the 0 comes, all points are gone. The program should stop the round as soon as a score over 10 is reached or a 0 comes. The results should be added at the end.

We are now at the point where the points are added and fields are fixed, but we can't think of anything to do with stopping or adding the results.

Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks in advance!

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class RandomBeispielzwei {

    private static final Map<Double, Integer> GRENZEN = new LinkedHashMap<Double, Integer>();

    static {
      GRENZEN.put(0.1, 1);
      GRENZEN.put(0.2, 2);
      GRENZEN.put(0.3, 3);
      GRENZEN.put(0.4, 1);
      GRENZEN.put(0.5, 2);
      GRENZEN.put(0.6, 3);
      GRENZEN.put(0.7, 1);
      GRENZEN.put(0.8, 2);
      GRENZEN.put(0.9, 3);
      GRENZEN.put(1.0, 0); 
    }

    private Integer naechsteZufallzahl() {
      double random = Math.random();
      for (Map.Entry<Double, Integer> entry : GRENZEN.entrySet()) {
       if (random <= entry.getKey().doubleValue()) {
            return entry.getValue();
        }
      }

      throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Fuer die Zufallszahl wurde kein passender Wert in der Map gefunden");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      int anzahl1 = 0;
      int anzahl2 = 0;
      int anzahl3 = 0;
      int anzahl0 = 0;
      RandomBeispielzwei b = new RandomBeispielzwei();

      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        
        Integer z = b.naechsteZufallzahl();
        if (z.intValue() == 1) {
            anzahl1++;
        } else if (z.intValue() == 2) {
            anzahl2++;
        } else if (z.intValue() == 3) {
            anzahl3++;
        } else {
            anzahl0++;
        }
      }
      int ges1 = anzahl1 * 1; 
      int ges2 = anzahl1 * 2;   
      int ges3 = anzahl1 * 3;
    
      System.out.println("1: " + anzahl1);
      System.out.println("Punktzahl 1: " + ges1);
      System.out.println("2: " + anzahl2);
      System.out.println("Punktzahl 2: " + ges2);
      System.out.println("3: " + anzahl3);
      System.out.println("Punktzahl 3: " + ges3);
      System.out.println("0: " + anzahl0);
      System.out.println("Gesamtzahl: " + (anzahl1 + anzahl2 + anzahl3 + anzahl0));
      System.out.println("Gesamtpunktzahl: " + (ges1 + ges2 + ges3));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you repeat spin 10000 times if you say you need to stop spin immediately if `z == 0` or `sum == 10`. And the question - the sum of that? keys, or values of the map?

Answer (score 1):

For exiting the for-loop (and any other loop), you  can use the "break" statement, which simply ends the loop (similar to how "return" will exit a method). In order to be able to stop once the total score reaches ten, you of course need to keep track of the total score. To do this, the easiest way would be to introduce aa integer variable (e.g. "gesamtpunktzahl"), to which you add the amount of points scored in each turn. In all, it would look something like this:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class RandomBeispielZwei {
    private static final Map<Double, Integer> GRENZEN = new LinkedHashMap<Double, Integer>();

    static {
    GRENZEN.put(0.1, 1);
    GRENZEN.put(0.2, 2);
    GRENZEN.put(0.3, 3);
    GRENZEN.put(0.4, 1);
    GRENZEN.put(0.5, 2);
    GRENZEN.put(0.6, 3);
    GRENZEN.put(0.7, 1);
    GRENZEN.put(0.8, 2);
    GRENZEN.put(0.9, 3);
    GRENZEN.put(1.0, 0);

    }

    private Integer naechsteZufallzahl() {
        double random = Math.random();
        for (Map.Entry<Double, Integer> entry : GRENZEN.entrySet()) {
           if (random <= entry.getKey().doubleValue()) {
                return entry.getValue();
            }
    }

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Fuer die Zufallszahl wurde kein passender Wert in der Map gefunden");
}

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int anzahl1 = 0;
        int anzahl2 = 0;
        int anzahl3 = 0;
        int anzahl0 = 0;
        int gesamtpunktzahl = 0;  // this will store what the total score is so far
        RandomBeispielzwei b = new RandomBeispielzwei();

  
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            
            Integer z = b.naechsteZufallzahl();
            if (z.intValue() == 1) {
                anzahl1++;
                gesamtpunktzahl++; // a 1 was scored, so we increase the total score by 1
            } else if (z.intValue() == 2) {
                anzahl2++;
                gesamtpunktzahl += 2;  // same with a 2
            } else if (z.intValue() == 3) {
                anzahl3++;
                gesamtpunktzahl += 3;  // same with a 3
            } else {
                anzahl0++;
                break;  // a 0 was rolled, so we end the game (by exiting the for-loop)
            }
            
            if (gesamtpunktzahl >= 10) break;  // at least 10 points were scored so far, so we exit the for-loop
        }
        int ges1 = anzahl1 * 1; 
        int ges2 = anzahl1 * 2;   
        int ges3 = anzahl1 * 3;
    

        System.out.println("1: " + anzahl1);
        System.out.println("Punktzahl 1: " + ges1);
        System.out.println("2: " + anzahl2);
        System.out.println("Punktzahl 2: " + ges2);
        System.out.println("3: " + anzahl3);
        System.out.println("Punktzahl 3: " + ges3);
        System.out.println("0: " + anzahl0);
        System.out.println("Gesamtzahl: " + (anzahl1 + anzahl2 + anzahl3 + anzahl0));
        System.out.println("Gesamtpunktzahl: " + gesamtpunktzahl); // since we calculated it anyway, we might as well just use it here
    
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the loop `do ... while` for the counting and printing.
And please check you code - does you need count the same variable `anzahl1` for each `ges`?:

```
  int ges1 = anzahl1 * 1; 
  int ges2 = anzahl1 * 2;   
  int ges3 = anzahl1 * 3;
```

if not - then replace `ges[i] = anzahles[1] * (i+1);` to `ges[i] = anzahles[i+1] * (i+1);`

---

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] anzahles = new int[4];
        int gesamtpunktzahl = 0;
        Integer z = 0;
        RandomBeispielzwei b = new RandomBeispielzwei();

        do {
            z = b.naechsteZufallzahl();
            anzahles[z]++;
            gesamtpunktzahl += z;

        } while (!(z == 0 || gesamtpunktzahl >= 10));

        int ges[] = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ges[i] = anzahles[1] * (i+1);
            System.out.println((i+1) + ": " + anzahles[i+1]);
            System.out.println("Punktzahl " + (i+1) + ": " + ges[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("0: " + anzahles[0]);
        System.out.println("Gesamtzahl: " + Arrays.stream(anzahles).sum());
        System.out.println("Gesamtpunktzahl: " + Arrays.stream(ges).sum());
    }
```